# Adding everyone to local group using vbscript

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, vbscript

What would be an alternative in vbscript to

```
NET LOCALGROUP /ADD "Power Users" Everyone
```

I know how to add a single group or user but Everyone isn't found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can script the 'everyone' built-in group and you probably shouldn't.  MS best practice says not to assign resource permissions or user rights to this account. Use Authenticated Users or specific user accounts and groups where necessary.  More info here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277461.aspx